# How to pass an ko.observableArray to an MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I want to pass an array of strings from my view model (in form of an `ko.observableArray`) to the controller in Asp.net MVC.

As the `ko.observableArray` is an object rather than array, it cannot simply be passed through the `$.ajax` method and used as array in controller side.

How can I pass the data in `ko.observableArray` to controller so that I can use it as array on the controller side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knockout has two utility function called `ko.toJS` and `ko.toJSON`.

`var myPlainObject = ko.toJS(root)` will traverse your object and turn any observable into a plain JavaScript property.

`var myJSONstring = ko.toJSON(root)` will do the same and then do a `JSON.stringify` on the result.

So, you can use those functions on your viewModel to get plain JavaScript objects.

Info from the docs [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html).

If the items in your observableArray do not contain observables, then you could simply just retrieve the underlying array by doing `myObservableArray()`

Update: based on comment.  This works fine for me:

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray(["one", "two", "three", "four"]),
    sendItems: function() {
          $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Test")",
            data: ko.toJSON(viewModel.items),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    alert(ko.toJSON(data));
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Against an action like:

```
    //just echo back data
    public JsonResult Test(List<String> myList)
    {
        return Json(myList);
    }
```

Does this match what you are trying?

Comment: Thanks for your help again, for my case, the observableArray is storing an array of string, I want to retrieve the array in controller side so that I can use a loop on it, like this: 

>> public JsonResult Test(List<String> myObservableArray)


But if I send it directly that it pass a object rather than a array that I can't get the string by loop inside the observableArray.

I have tried to use ko.toJSON() but I still can't figure out how to get the observableArray and convert to a string array in controller side.